# Alternative form for Django's `ChoiceField` that can handle thousands of entries

Tags: django, forms, widget, scalability

I have a form with a `ChoiceField` in it. It is rendered to the user as a dropdown box.

Problem is, I have thousands of entries in this field, which is causing the page to (a) load very slowly and (b) be sluggish.

I want an alternative widget, instead of `Select`, that could handle more than 10,000 choices.

Something like the admin's `raw_id_fields` would be good (if only it were usable in general forms...) but I'm open to ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If autocomplete is an option for your UI you can take a look to [django-simple-autocomplete](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-simple-autocomplete):

> App enabling the use of jQuery UI autocomplete widget for
>   ModelChoiceFields with minimal configuration required.

**EDITED**  (reply OP comment)

I have not tested this solution, but digging documentation and source it seems that not all data is loaded at a time:

> The ability to specify an URL for the widget enables you to hook up to
>   other more advanced autocomplete query engines if you wish.

[Source code](https://github.com/praekelt/django-simple-autocomplete/blob/master/simple_autocomplete/views.py):

```
def get_json(request, token):
    """Return matching results as JSON"""
            ...
            di = {'%s__istartswith' % fieldname: searchtext}     # <- look here!
            items = queryset.filter(**di).order_by(fieldname)[:10]
```

[Widget source code](https://github.com/praekelt/django-simple-autocomplete/blob/master/simple_autocomplete/widgets.py)

```
$("#id_%(name)s_helper").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response){
        $.ajax({                                  # <-- look here
            url: "%(url)s",
            data: {q: request.term},
            success: function(data) {
```

Comment: Looking at the jQuery demo for this widget, it seems to me that it necessitates including *all* of the options as part of the HTML. This will not solve my problem, because including thousands of usernames in an HTML page would make it load very slowly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the raw_id_fields but why not use a model to store all your choices ?

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    value = models.CharField()

class MyModel(models.Model):
    choice = models.ForeignKey(Choice)
```

It would then be easy to select it if you want to display only 20 at a time for example.

Comment: I don't understand how this would even work.

Let me clarify my task: I have 10,000 users. I have a form in which you choose a user. You need to be able to choose any user you want. You can't just load 20, because then you won't be able to choose the other 9,980 users. (Pagination isn't an option, because having to scroll through 100s of pages of users would be terrible.)

Comment: Ok I hadn't understand your question correctly. So I think, the burhan's solution is maybe the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Based on this comment (which really, you should have included in your question):

> Let me clarify my task: I have 10,000 users. I have a form in which
>   you choose a user. You need to be able to choose any user you want.
>   You can't just load 20, because then you won't be able to choose the
>   other 9,980 users.

If you want something built-in, you can use the [FilteredSelectMultiple](https://code.djangoproject.com/browser/django/tags/releases/1.3.1/django/contrib/admin/widgets.py) widget from `django.contrib.admin.widgets`, which puts a filter on your select.

You should also [cache](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/cache/) the results of the 10,000 users so you don't hit your db everytime. This is what is causing your delay, not the number of users (which is tiny, for practical performance problems).